# How to test a class with delegate in constructor using Moq

Tags: moq

Can someone explain to me how to create an instance of this component in a Moq TestMethod? Here is the definition of the class. I need to test the ProcessAutomaticFillRequest method.

```
public class AutomaticDispenserComponent : IAutomaticDispenserComponent
{
    private readonly Lazy<IMessageQueueComponent> _messageQueueComponent;
    protected IMessageQueueComponent MessageQueueComponent { get { return _messageQueueComponent.Value; } }

    public AutomaticDispenserComponent(Func<IMessageQueueComponent> messageQueueComponentFactory)
    {
        _messageQueueComponent = new Lazy<IMessageQueueComponent>(messageQueueComponentFactory);
    }

    public void ProcessAutomaticFillRequest(FillRequestParamDataContract fillRequestParam)
    {
        if (fillRequestParam.PrescriptionServiceUniqueId == Guid.Empty)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No prescription service was specified for processing fill request.");

        if (fillRequestParam.Dispenser == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No dispenser was specified for processing fill request.");

        var userContext = GlobalContext.CurrentUserContext;

        var channel = string.Format(Channel.FillRequest, userContext.TenantId,
            userContext.PharmacyUid, fillRequestParam.Dispenser.DeviceAgentUniqueId);

        NotificationServer.Publish(channel, fillRequestParam);
    }
```

Here is how I started my test, but I don't know how to create an instance of the component:

```
[TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof (InvalidOperationException))]
    public void FillRequestFailsWhenPrescriptionServiceUniqueIdIsEmpty()
    {
        // How do I create an instance of automatiqueDispenserComponent here 
        // since there is Func as constructor parameter?

        var fillRequestParam = new FillRequestParamDataContract
        {
            PrescriptionServiceUniqueId = Guid.Empty
        };

        _automaticDispensercomponent.ProcessAutomaticFillRequest(fillRequestParam);

        // ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated the answer based on the comments below. You need to mock the Func parameter for the test.

```
    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(InvalidOperationException))]
    public void FillRequestFailsWhenPrescriptionServiceUniqueIdIsEmpty()
    {
        var mockMsgQueueComponent = new Mock<Func<IMessageQueueComponent>>();

        var _automaticDispensercomponent = new AutomaticDispenserComponent
            (mockMsgQueueComponent.Object);

        var fillRequestParam = new FillRequestParamDataContract
        {
            PrescriptionServiceUniqueId = Guid.Empty
        };

        _automaticDispensercomponent.ProcessAutomaticFillRequest(fillRequestParam);
    }
```

Comment: I'll give this a try. But should the variable name be called mock though? You're not really creating a mock of anything. In my test I'll be executing an actual method of this component. It's the method that I'm testing.

Comment: I don't want to mock the component because that's the class I'm testing. I'm testing one of its methods. I reworded my question with more information. Hopefully, that would help. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Its clear now after you provided more information. I updated the answer.

Comment: Excellent! I didn't know you can mock the delegate. Never thought of that. Thanks !